# How can I program my mcu stm32f103 to transmit and receive data via a server

Tags: stm32, gsm, sim

hello I am a beginner and my final project is an alarm system, in fact I use a mcu stm32f103 and I want to transmit the data by a GSM module to a base (to access it by a mobile application) and also receive on/off commands through an application
if it is possible to help me in the programming part
thank you very much

Comment: Is this using an eval board?

Comment: If you can run https commands you can easily poke data into a [Ubidots](https://www.ubidots.com/) database.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have some extent of digital electronics background: Read a book covering cortex-m3 (for example Joseph Yiu's book) + explore the essential product sheets: the "datasheet", the programming manual, the reference manual etc // meanwhile learn C. Then you will figure out what to do yourself.